# how to use react-spring parallax on the main window

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

this is my first time implementing the  react-parallax effect, the goal is to use the parallax tag on some sections but not all, but no matter what i try the parallax tag seems to just create a separate container in those sections and i end up with two sroll bars. i just want to know if theres no way to implement the parallax effect and just use the window scrollbar as the only scrollbar.

```
import { Parallax, ParallaxLayer } from '@react-spring/parallax'

const Cards = () => {
   

   

    return (
        <>
             <Titlebar title= 'Three major ethnic groups' />
             <Parallax pages={3}>
      <ParallaxLayer sticky={{ start: 1, end: 3 }} style={{  justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
          <Test text='bole' paragraph='gimme that bole' source= {igbo} alter='igbo' />
        </ParallaxLayer>


        <ParallaxLayer offset={0} speed={0.5} style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <p >Scroll down</p>
        </ParallaxLayer>

        

        <ParallaxLayer offset={1.5} speed={1.5} style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <div>
            <p>I'm not</p>
          </div>
        </ParallaxLayer>
      </Parallax>
        </>
    )
}

export default Cards
```

this is some sample code from my project, to explain again. i want to be able to use to use just the window scrollbar to scroll through all the elements in the page